# "ORA-01722: invalid number" when passing property to IN statement in Data Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a SQL query in Data Service:

SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN (?)

where '?' is a list if ID's separated by comma. When I manually put ID's in query (IN (1234, 1235)) it works, but when I try to pass them through String property {id=1234, 1235} Im getting ORA-01722: invalid number. This how I define my input param, I guess it's something with data types but I cant seem to make it work.

```
<param type="IN" name="id" optional="false" sqlType="STRING" paramType="SCALAR" />
```

Comment: Can you share how you set the property?

Comment: I use xquery to create element
<ns1:ID>1234, 1235</ns1:ID>
Then I sent it to DataService as 'id' using expression $ctx:xqResult/*/*[local-name() = 'ID']
It works when there's only one ID but more results in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround how about parsing a dynamic query string?

```xml
<sql>SELECT ... FROM ... :fquery</sql>
<param name="fquery" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="QUERY_STRING"/>
```

In the request.

```
GET ....../YOUR_SERVICE?fquery=WHERE id IN (1234, 1235)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I created IN statement elsewhere and then sent it as QUERY_STRING and it works, thanks!